# Could not load image from HTML page

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make a web site in code, and I added an image to the page: `<img src"../img/image.png">`. When I load the page in a browser I get a square box, and it says it could not load image.

I have tried it in Windows 10 and Kubuntu 18.04 - same error. I get the same error when I make a CSS file. If I put the image in the root folder it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Any sample code?

Comment: post your code, your file path is probably wrong

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Should be
`<img src="../img/image.png">`. You are missing the `=`

Answer (score 0):

did not work here the top of my html page same error only way it works it I put ../WebSite/img for the folder . But when I ftp the page no logo or background . But the files are there

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <img src="../img/Logo.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the assets folder, that folder include the images folder then i paste the png type image (bill.png) in image directory.

Here is the code with image path

`<img src="{{ asset('assets/images/bill.png') }}" class="center-block">`

**Important thing**
assets folder in public directory

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in the same folder as the webpage is and try to change source to that image name.
                                     OR
Try clearing your browser cache data if you want image to be loaded from assests folder.